# Is there already package in python which generate strong random sequence which uses only digits?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using uuid package in python to generate random code, but it uses digits and characters.
Is there already package in python which generate strong random sequence which uses only digits ?
( At the moment I have two option to generate sequence(36 digits) by generating every digit by calling random() or to convert character to digit but I don't if this is strong random enough).

Comment: So you want unique or strong random numerical sequences?

Comment: Why do you think `random` isn't strong enough? I'd simply do: `random.randint(10**36, 10**37-1)`, or split the range into 4 9-digit numbers and generate those...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The uuid returned by Python is actually a class, so you can get it in different formats easily:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4().int
27168693431722041803402778536822837233
```

Here's the online help for the UUID type. You want the `int` attribute.

```
>>> help(uuid.UUID)
Help on class UUID in module uuid:

class UUID(builtins.object)
 |  Instances of the UUID class represent UUIDs as specified in RFC 4122.
 |  UUID objects are immutable, hashable, and usable as dictionary keys.
 |  Converting a UUID to a string with str() yields something in the form
 |  '12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc'.  The UUID constructor accepts
 |  five possible forms: a similar string of hexadecimal digits, or a tuple
 |  of six integer fields (with 32-bit, 16-bit, 16-bit, 8-bit, 8-bit, and
 |  48-bit values respectively) as an argument named 'fields', or a string
 |  of 16 bytes (with all the integer fields in big-endian order) as an
 |  argument named 'bytes', or a string of 16 bytes (with the first three
 |  fields in little-endian order) as an argument named 'bytes_le', or a
 |  single 128-bit integer as an argument named 'int'.
 |  
 |  UUIDs have these read-only attributes:
 |  
 |      bytes       the UUID as a 16-byte string (containing the six
 |                  integer fields in big-endian byte order)
 |  
 |      bytes_le    the UUID as a 16-byte string (with time_low, time_mid,
 |                  and time_hi_version in little-endian byte order)
 |  
 |      fields      a tuple of the six integer fields of the UUID,
 |                  which are also available as six individual attributes
 |                  and two derived attributes:
 |  
 |          time_low                the first 32 bits of the UUID
 |          time_mid                the next 16 bits of the UUID
 |          time_hi_version         the next 16 bits of the UUID
 |          clock_seq_hi_variant    the next 8 bits of the UUID
 |          clock_seq_low           the next 8 bits of the UUID
 |          node                    the last 48 bits of the UUID
 |  
 |          time                    the 60-bit timestamp
 |          clock_seq               the 14-bit sequence number
 |  
 |      hex         the UUID as a 32-character hexadecimal string
 |  
 |      int         the UUID as a 128-bit integer
 |  
 |      urn         the UUID as a URN as specified in RFC 4122
 |  
 |      variant     the UUID variant (one of the constants RESERVED_NCS,
 |                  RFC_4122, RESERVED_MICROSOFT, or RESERVED_FUTURE)
 |  
 |      version     the UUID version number (1 through 5, meaningful only
 |                  when the variant is RFC_4122)
 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `uuid`. UUIDs are represented as hexadecimal strings, separated by hyphens. So you can get a decimal UUID by stripping all hyphens from a UUID (in order to turn it into a single hexadecimal representation) and representing it as decimal instead of hexadecimal:

```
hex_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
hex_uuid = str(hex_uuid).replace("-", "")
decimal_uuid = str(int(hex_uuid, 16))
```

One liner:

```
decimal_uuid = str(int(str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", ""), 16))
```

**EDIT** Duncan's answer points to a simpler way for performing the transformation above.

However, you should remember that **UUIDs are not exactly "strongly random"**, they are only guaranteed to be unique (well, until some point in the future).

If you need cryptographically-strong (i.e. *very* strong) random numbers, then you should go for a crypto lib wrapper, such as [M2Crypto](https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto) for OpenSSL:

```
from M2Crypto.Rand import rand_bytes, rand_seed

# Maybe seed with rand_seed("seed with a very random string, not like this")
decimal_id = str(int(rand_bytes(64).encode("hex"), 16))
```

this is guaranteed to be cryptographically strong, but not to be unique (i.e. generating the same id twice is possible, although extremely improbable for some definition of "improbable").

Comment: Do your examples actually work? I would have thought you would have to convert the `UUID` object to a string before you can use the `replace()` method.

Comment: Yes they work, that was a typo (I expanded it from the one liner). Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how **strong** uuid is so why not simply rely on the operating system to make the random for you?

```
import os
32_bytes_of_random = os.urandom(32)
```

It'll be as **strong** as the random that the OS uses but I'm not sure how well you can rely on that. Additionally the problem is if you want to represent this "random" data in just digits and not alphanumeric for it's going to take a lot more characters.

If you're looking for serious crypto random in Python checkout the work at [cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/). There was a great review at PyCon 2014 up on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_Pj__qjBvA).